# How to format calculated measure in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've created a new measure in Power BI with the below DAX formula, it throws me an error of saying 
"The following syntax error occurred during parsing: Invalid token, Line 18, Offset 61, %."

```
New_Measure = 
 if(VALUES(POC[report]) = "A",
     Format ( (CALCULATE( 
     [Value Measure],
         FILTER(
                 ALL(POC),
                 POC[report]="B"),                                                                                                                                                                                   
                 VALUES( POC[project_number]
                )
                ) /
     CALCULATE(
     [Value Measure],
         FILTER(
                 ALL(POC),
                 POC[report]="C"),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                 VALUES( POC[project_number]
                )
               )) 0.00%), Format([Value Measure], $#,##0;($#,##0)))
```

How to resolve this error? any help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma before `0.00%` in the final line, and you need to enclose your format string in quotes::

```
           )), "0.00%"), Format([Value Measure], "$#,##0;($#,##0)"))
```

I'd strongly recommend trying https://www.daxformatter.com - it will help you debug typos like this more easily.